# Need to add new row when TAB out of the last cell of the the ag-grid

Tags: angular5, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Inside an ag-grid, if a user hits TAB, it automatically advances the user to the next field. If the user is in the last column in the grid and TAB's out, I would like that tab to automatically "add row" and position the cursor in the first column of the new row.

1. I have the code to add a new row.
2. I need to know how to programmatically determine a tab out in the last column/cell of the grid?

Comment: You can use the `tabToNextCell` call back to manually add a new row once you've reached the end, see [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#tabtonextcell)

Comment: I need the default code provided by ag-grid. So that I can tweak it as per my requirement. Basically, on tab out of the last cell in the grid, I want to add logic to add a new row